# Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of undefined (vue + leaflet)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

Getting this error while trying to add a feature group to my map:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of undefined

Code fragment that throws the error:

```
<l-map
  id="mapid"
  :zoom="zoom"
  :center="center"
/>


var map = document.getElementById("mapid").__vue__;
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
```

Using:

```
leaflet 1.5.1,
leaflet-draw 1.0.4,
vue 2.6.10,
vue2-leaflet 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `addLayer` is not part of the public API for the `l-map` component. Even if it were, the 'layer' passed to `addLayer` needs to be the Vue2Leaflet wrapper component, not the underlying Leaflet layer.

To see this, consider the code in `LFeatureGroup.vue`:

https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet/blob/940e17d8a3b19740a448dedf220d0f7ba9c61d31/src/components/LFeatureGroup.vue#L27

Notice how it calls:

```js
this.parentContainer.addLayer(this);
```

Here `this` refers to an instance of the Vue component `l-feature-group`, whereas the underlying Leaflet `FeatureGroup` is in the `this.mapObject` property.

I suggest that you try to use the `l-feature-group` component instead. Something like:

```html
<l-map
  id="mapid"
  :zoom="zoom"
  :center="center"
>
  <l-feature-group>
    <!-- relevant children -->
  </l-feature-group>
</l-map>
```

There's a good example in the documentation:

https://korigan.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/#/components/l-feature-group/

I also strongly recommend that you avoid using `document.getElementById("mapid").__vue__` as a way to grab the Vue instance. Use `ref` and `$refs` instead.